# Discord.js : detect when user gets disconnected, and by whom

Tags: discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a discord bot who 'avenges me'.
With discord.js, is it possible to detect when a user (me) gets disconnected from voice channel by another user, and know who the latter is, so that i can be avenged.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's what I found that gets the closest to what I wanted to do ;

```js
async function discoAvenger() {
    // disco(nnection) avenger, not 80's IronMan dancing eh

    const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get(config.guildId);
       // targeted discord server
    const fetchedLogs = await guild.fetchAuditLogs(({ limit: 1 }));
       // fetch the logs of that server (returns an array)
    const auditLogEntry = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
       // select the first logs of that array

    if (auditLogEntry.action == 27) {
      // if the logs is a "player got disconnected from vocal" (unintentionally)
        console.log("27 it is");
        const now = new Date();
        const diff = now.getTime() - auditLogEntry.createdTimestamp;
           // get the time diff between now and the log27
        const member = guild.members.cache.get(auditLogEntry.executor.id);
           // fetch who disconnected someone
        if (diff < 5000) {
           // use diff to know if the log27 was created less than 5s ago
           // else the member would be disconnected even if the log27 was created 1h ago
            console.log("log27 > 5s")
            console.log(member.id)
            if (member.id !== config.clientId) {
              // if the member who disconnected someone is not the bot
                console.log("I dit not do it. -T. Lannister");
                member.voice.setChannel(null);
                   // disconnect the member for revenge
                console.log(`disconnected ${member.displayName}`);

           // here i just tried to create and delete a dummy channel, i'll explain down there
                const channel = guild.channels.create({
                    name: "Dummy",
                    type: Discord.ChannelType.GuildVoice,
                    parent: "911348246327210039",
                });
                channel.delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
setInterval(discoAvenger, 5000);  // repeat every 5s to check if there is a new log27
```

Here's the thing; (my assumption)

Discord has it's ways of generating the server's logs.
Disconnect someone, and a log is created.

> "Ding disconnected 1 user"

Disconnect another someone between the first log creation and a certain amount of time and a second log is not created, but the first is updated

> "Ding disconnect 2 users"

And this is where it ends, it's not possible (to the best of my knowledge) to detect that log update.

This is why i tried to create and delete dummy channel, thus creating 2 logs after the deconnection, to see if the log27 would still be updated or a new one created, but even with 2 different newer logs, it gets updated.

The code works, but only once every x minutes. (the time it waits before created a new log, not updating an older one).

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will never know by who you've been disconnected. This is not possible using the Discord API.

You can still detect when you are disconnected:

```js
voiceConnection.on("disconnect", () => {
   console.log("I've been disconnnected...");
});
```

Comment: Does this trigger only when you get disconnected, or also when you disconnect by yourself ?
alternatively, is there a way to access the server's logs ? maybe with the logs i could work my way up where i want to

Comment: 1) in both cases
2) you can access server logs using a bot. The thing is that, even with a user account, kicks from voice channels are not logged there.

Comment: thanks, a very last question: can i disconnect someone with a bot who has admin rights, when i don't have them ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.